# Copy trunk to tag without trunk folder

Tags: svn, command-line

I would like to copy my trunk to a specific tag. I tried this command line :

```
svn copy http://svn/PROJECT/trunk http://svn/PROJECT/tags/T1.01_PROJECT -m "my message"
```

it works but it copies the trunk folder... I would like to copy what is inside the trunk folder to the tag folder.

Can u help ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

That will only happen, if the tag destination directory already exists before you do the copy. To do what you want, don't create the tag first. This mirrors a copy operation in your shell. Consider the difference between this:

```
mkdir foo
touch foo/bar
mkdir waffles
mv foo waffles
```

compared to this:

```
mkdir foo
touch foo/bar
mv foo waffles
```

The first will put the "foo" directory within the "waffles" directory. The second will change the name of "foo" to "waffles".

SVN acts the same way.

Comment: In addition to @Ben's correct answer, you should look into some pre-commit hooks that make tags immutable that would prevent this and other shenanigans in tags.  There are lots of ways to do this, I'd start by checking out http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/branches/master-passphrase/tools/hook-scripts/svnperms.py

Comment: you mean there is no simple command to say copy what is inside this folder to another one ?

Comment: Are you not paying any attention? I said you should not need to do that. In addition, if you DO manage to do it, your tag will no longer look like a tag. Delete your existing tag and copy it correctly and you will have no problems. You *can* `svn copy` each item within trunk, but now the tag will not show up in any revision graphs or other software that parses your SVN tree. Don't do it that way. Do it the right way and svn copy the trunk itself to a new folder. If that new folder doesn't already exist, you'll get exactly what you want. If the new folder exists already, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: How do you avoid checking out all the tags?

Comment: Just check out a path that is not above the tags. For example: trunk. Please ask (or search for) a new question if you need a more detailed response, this question and answer don't really have anything to do with checkouts.